# Adaptive Cards : Dynamic data binding on Action.Show Card

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I am working on Adaptive Cards in Teams.

I am able to send a card and update the card based on the user action.

However i am wondering if it is possible to load data in the Adaptive Card dynamically by calling a REST API when Action.ShowCard is called. For Example in the below, When clicked on More Info, I would like to call an API and then populate the ShowCard data with the API responses. Is there any way we can achieve this ?

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reaching out to us We will investigate and if we require further information we will reach out. Best regards, Teams Platform

Comment: **Thank You** for accepting answer, this will help others in the community with similar question. Could you please spare one min to let us know how we did by clicking on **[this feedback link](https://aka.ms/DevSupportFeedback)**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not bind data dynamically onclicking of the action.showcard button using api call because the action.showcard's card will loads with the parent card so when click on showcard it will shows what ever loaded initially. This is by design